# Can a hypothetical question be in past tense? Please see my example

Tags: tenses

If you **passed** a subject without learning anything valuable about it, did that subject really help you?

Comment: If you had passed any subject back then, I would have been amazed.

Comment: Do you think "did" is the right verb to use?

Comment: I think for  a general rule, the enduring present would be preferred:  "If you pass a subject without learning anything about it, you waste your time."  For something more specific:  "If you passed a subject in 2010 or before, your transcript has been updated to remove the credit."  Note that these aren't conditions contrary to fact requiring the "subjunctive."  That would be "If you were to have passed a subject," which is clumsy enough that I can't recall actually hearing it.  Your example is grammatical, I believe.

Comment: The example you give is perfectly valid syntax and semantics, reasonably idiomatic (for US speech, at least), and would, absent contextual clues to the contrary, normally be interpreted as referring to a hypothetical situation.  It is not necessary for the syntax to unambiguously signal "hypothetical" for the question to, in fact, be hypothetical.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply: yes.

A hypothetical is just supposing that something is true so the often proposed hypothetical "what would it be like now **if the enemy had won the war**" is perfectly fine and, in fact, a very convenient example.

In slight deviation from the question:
As @CopperKettle said, your example is not technically a hypothetical, but that doesn't affect the answer, just a note on the side.

Answer (score 0):

A hypothetical question is really just a hypothetical scenario (the conditional statement) followed by a question that inquires about the potential consequences of the unreal event.

As it is now, the example implies that the past scenario is real rather than hypothetical, and that the question is asked in the context of that given scenario. @deadrat has provided an example hypothetical scenario, the nature of which is indicated by the use of the past perfect form of the verb. The tense of the question should reflect the time in which the results would occur - so the use of 'did' in the question implies that the time when the subject would have helped has concluded.

[Conditional verb forms](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional.htm)