# The word/idea that warns against thinking 'If only the past had A, then B'

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, in this conversation:

> Person A: "If only we had player X back then, we would have won by an even greater margin!"
>
> Person B: "No, I don't subscribe to that idea. Player Y did a fine job, we won the title with player Y, and some would even argue we won because of player Y. Substituting in player X sounds nice as a hypothetical concept in the present but there's no telling what might've happened actually with them on the team back then."

I believe the word for the idea exists as I once heard it on a podcast but neglected to write it down.

Comment: It was an English word.

Comment: If only we **had had player x back then** etc. **wishful thinking** is the term.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of ***post hoc ergo propter hoc*** reasoning. In particular, A is assuming that player A's absence is the cause of the smaller margin of victory, when the two could be unrelated. As [Wikipedia defines it:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc)

> ***Post hoc ergo propter hoc*** (Latin: 'after this, therefore because of this') is an informal fallacy that states: "Since event Y *followed* event X, event Y must have been *caused* by event X." It is often shortened simply to ***post hoc* fallacy.**

Comment: I think that could be it, although in my head I recall a more eloquent and perhaps antiquated expression, certainly one not often used. It was within the context of an interview where the interviewer suggested "If only we had this weapon, then we could've won the war earlier." To which the interviewee responded, "Well we still won, and there would not have any guarantees on the implications of having used that weapon against the enemy, so better to just leave history as is."

Comment: This is over the top for podcast as given in the question/

Answer (score 0):

I would argue this could be referred to as a "hypothetical". There are certainly suggestions that musings about past possibilities can be described this way, such as [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294894/can-a-hypothetical-question-be-in-past-tense-please-see-my-example).

Answer (score 0):

*Counterfactual history* may be the term you heard.

It tries at times to be more than merely speculative. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_history

Answer (score 0):

I'd use 'idle speculation' here; I'm not sure there's a single word available, though there might be an expression focusing more closely on mooning about *the past* ('if only').

Apparently J. Paul Getty is credited with the appropriate

- 'Nostalgia often leads to idle speculation.' [[BrainyQuote](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/j_paul_getty_280137)]